# Feasible condition of an optimisation problem with linear contraints

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

What is the condition so that the feasible set of the following optimization problem is not empty ?
$$
\max\limits_{x} f(x) \\
s.t.\quad A_i^T x \le a_i, \, i=1,\dots,N \\
x_i \le b, \, i=1,...,n
$$ 
where $x=[x_1,\dots,x_n] \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A_i$ are the vectors. $a_i$ and $b$ are constants and $f(x)$ is some function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions like these are answered by Farkas lemma with variants

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farkas%27_lemma